# Abstract Class Vs. [Interface+Inheritance] in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

In context of Java, could a class replace the need of extending an abstract class by extending another non-abstract class and implementing an interface together, both of which combined have all the methods(abstract and implemented), of an abstract class?

Comment: Your question is kind of confusing, can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: That said, I'm under the impression that a very common practice is, in fact, to use mainly interfaces to describe types of objects, and use inheritance (or composition) primarily for sharing code between classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In context of Java, could a class replace the need of extending an
>   abstract class by extending another non-abstract class and
>   implementing an interface together, both of which combined have all
>   the methods(abstract and implemented), of an abstract class?

Can it? Yes

Should it? No

An abstract class can be replaced by a concrete one, but you will be altering your system.

Do remember: an abstract class can not be instantiated, nor should it be, since it's not 'concrete enough' to make sense for your business. (If it does, it shouldn't have been an abstract class to begin with)

If you make it concrete, you risk that developers will use instances of the (what-should-be) abstract class.

If you change it the way you propose:

```
public void doSomething(MyAbstractClass instance){
  // here we know there is an implementation provided by a subclass
}
```

would become

```
public void doSomething(MyShouldBeAbstractClass instance){
  // here they can pass instances of the base class, which might have unsupported methods
}
```

For instance:

```
public String getConcreteInformation(){ 
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Should be called on a child class");
}
```

and could lead to a lot of nasty bugs

Comment: how does the `MyShouldBeAbstractClass` have unsupported methods?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko depends on the structure. Normally, in order to get a decent response on the state (that makes sense), it requires the information from the child classes. if not, the class wouldn't have been designed as an abstract class.
If you would replace the abstract class by a concrete implementation, that might lead to issues with it's child-classes.
Or you would need to make (for each implementation a) class/interface combinations, which I assume is not the target